# F# interactive - "reset session" hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, hotkeys, f#-interactive, fsi

I have assigned a new Global hotkey to

> VS 2010/Options/Environment/Keyboard/OtherContextMenus.FSIConsoleContext.ResetSession

But it seems to work only in the FSI window. How can I make the hotkey work globally?

Comment: It says FSIConsoleContext, what do you mean by resetting session globally?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is to hit a hotkey while writing the F# code (i.e. being in the editor window) to reset the FSI console window without even taking focus to the FSI window. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it the way you describe it (the hotkey will only work within the context of the FSI window), but you can use a VS Macro to change the focus to the FSI console, reset the session and move back;

the following worked for me: (needs additional error handling etc)

```
Sub ResetFSharpMacro()
    Dim WindowName As String
    WindowName = DTE.ActiveDocument.Name
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.F#Interactive")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("OtherContextMenus.FSIConsoleContext.ResetSession")
    DTE.Windows.Item(WindowName).Activate()
End Sub
```

You can then use `Macros.MyMacro....` to assign a global hotkey